# Limpar form ao entrar?

Tags: javascript, html, formulário

Existe a possibilidade de limpar o `form` ou os campos após a chamada sem o pressionamento de qualquer botão? No meu caso o usuário muda de menu e os dados continuam.

Menu de chamada: [Menu](http://jsfiddle.net/3HDy3/1/)

Pagina de conteúdo: [Conteudo](http://jsfiddle.net/VWnXS/1/)

Comment: Poderia explicar um pouco mais?

Comment: @RonnyAmarante a minha duvida é entrar na página e apagar os campos preenchidos (que no meu caso o usuário muda de menu e os dados continuam)

Comment: Isso deve estar ocorrendo se você usa inputs com mesmo nome.

Answer (score 1):

Sim há, pode chamar o reset da form com

```
document.getElementById('minhaForm').reset();
```

O que este método faz é restaurar os valores originais da form.

Se a form for submetida via AJAX, ie sem recarregar a página, pode juntar esse código em cima dentro da função success do AJAX.

Se a página carrega de novo, então os campos já vem limpos.

Esemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/8PaG2/

Comment: Nesse caso eu utilizo `document.getElementById('minhaForm').reset();` dentro da `<form>`?

Comment: @Isaias, você refere que muda de menu. Que código usa para essa mudança?

Comment: eu utilizo um menu com abas, e o problema é que quando abro a "aba principal" ele abre todos os outros e não fecha nenhum na mudança! obs* na aba principal que chama os dados!

Comment: @Isaias, pode colocar o seu código num jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) ou editar a pergunta e colocar lá? Assim vai ter ajuda para resolver esse problema também.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que dá para analisar nos JSFiddle na tua pergunta, os formulários referentes a cada aba encontram-se dentro de uma `iframe`. Assim sendo, deverás na função que cuida da alteração de aba, aplicar o seguinte código:

```js
// localizar a iFrame
var minhaFrame = document.getElementById( iframeID );

// localizar o conteudo da iframe
var minhaFrameDoc = minhaFrame.contentDocument || minhaFrame.contentWindow.document;

// localizar o formulário dentro da iframe pelo ID do formulario
var meuFormulario = minhaFrameDoc.getElementById( formID );

// repor formulário a vazio conforme resposta do @Sergio
meuFormulario.reset();
```

A tua função `Alter()` ficará:

```js
function Alter(menu,conteudo)
{
  for (i=0;i<arAbas.length;i++)
  {
   m = document.getElementById(arAbas[i].menu);
   m.className = 'menu';
   c = document.getElementById(arAbas[i].conteudo)
   c.style.display = 'none';
  }
  m = document.getElementById(menu)
  m.className = 'menu-sel';
  c = document.getElementById(conteudo)
  c.style.display = '';


  var minhaFrame = c.getElementById( iframeID );
  var minhaFrameDoc = minhaFrame.contentDocument || minhaFrame.contentWindow.document;
  var meuFormulario = minhaFrameDoc.getElementById( formID );

  // repor formulário a vazio conforme resposta do @Sergio
  meuFormulario.reset();
}
```

Para que isto funcione, deverás ter um `id` único em cada `iframe` bem como um `id` único em cada formulário:

**Iframe**

```
<table border="0" width="50%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <iframe id="iframeID" style="border-radius:20px;"  scrolling="no" src="../sai_cada_usua/sai_frm_incl_usua.php" width="830" height="310" >
      </iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Formulário**

```
<form name="sai_frm_incl_usua1" id="formID" action="sai_incl_usua" method="POST" autocomplete="off"  onsubmit="return f_veri_dados();">
  <!-- conteúdo do formulário -->
</form>
```

Desta forma, sempre que o utilizador clicar para mudar de aba, o formulário que vai ser apresentado será limpo via JavaScript, ficando assim sem nada preenchido nos campos do mesmo.